# Adjusting the my.cnf file for DB servers after an instance resize

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, centos

I am trying to optimize the DB server of one of our production environments (MySQL DB, centos7), and I've noticed that there is a very high memory consumption of the DB.

After further investigation I noticed that we should resize the DB from 8 GB RAM to 16 GB RAM due to increased usage. But when looking at the my.cnf file, I found the following settings for the buffer pool parameters:

```
#Pool size configuration
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6G
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=48
```

Now after checking [15.8.3.2 Configuring Multiple Buffer Pool Instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-multiple-buffer-pools.html) and a few other websites, it seems to point out that `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` should be set to **1 per CPU core**.

For some reason ours is `48`, and I couldn't find anyone in charge who could give me the reason for this.

I'd like to know if this setting could remain the same, which means it's probably there, because of a certain usage pattern?

This is a relatively small DB.

I will be resizing to 16 GB and adjusting the pool size to 12 GB, so it makes sense that `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` should be also set to `12`, from my very basic understanding. Am I correct with my assumption?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. I've taken the liberty of slightly rephrasing your quesiton. I hope you don't have any objections? Where did you read that it should be **1 per CPU core**? And what will you be resizing to 16 GB and what parameter to 12 GB? It's not quite clear. Could you hit [edit] to modify your question and be a bit more specific in explaining what exactly that you will be modifying? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most important change would be

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6G --> 12G
```

The number of buffer_pool_instances should be 1 per GB, not one per core.  So, 12 in your new machine.  However, there is a limit of 16.  As for why...

- I suspect it makes very little difference -- perhaps single-digit-percentage when the server is extremely busy.  (If a server is that busy, it is about to keel over; you have worse problems.)

Essentially nothing else requires changing.

After you have been running normally for at least a day, grab `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES`; then get an analysis here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning